# An Alternative to RDP?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, vnc

I use an ERP software for business whose data can't be kept at workplace for security reasons. I have two PCs for billing. If I host the company data online as FTP server, there is always a chance for disconnection which may cause data to be corrupted. I tried multiple RDP sessions on windows 10 with RDP wrapper library and XP/S terminal server but if even a small network disconnection is there, the user will log out causing sudden closing of software without the work being saved. VNC supports only 1 user. Is there any other alternative or is it possible to close and re-open RDP session without losing work?

EDIT: I have migrated to Windows server for multiple RDP sessions.. Thanks For Your Help...

Comment: WIndows 10 itself won't support multiple simultanious sessions. I've had no issues with a single session over RDP - I've been connecting to a box I own over the past few weeks with no disruption.

Comment: what do you mean by 'box'?

Comment: He’s referring to a PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the RDP session is lost cause various causes like network contention, you are **only disconnected**. You session is not closed, you are only disconnected. Then when you'll reconnect to the session (same user of course) and you'll retreive all informations, treatments and so on in your current session. You was just idle.

Often, i'm launching script file on remote computers, and this runs a long long time. Do you really think that i'm put my ass on the chair waiting for it to end and praying not to be disconnected ? No, I'm quit and the next day, I'll continue

It seems that you haven't this behaviour. Perhaps it's just the sleep settings (indeed, if the remote computer enter in a slepping mode, all activities stopped (network, disk, compute). Set settings according to you need. But perhaps these settings are set by a Group Policy. Then, contact you administrator to put a exclusion for your remote computer.

Oliv

Comment: It is the case in Windows server or only 1 RDP session. Windows 10 does not support multiple rdp sessions

Answer (score 0):

Answering strictly to the question from its title, beside the *VNC Viewer* you can always use the *TeamViewer*.

Also, recently there have appeared solutions directly from the web-browser.

Comment: Team Viewer does not support 2 different users on 1 computer

Comment: Good to know. So, apparently, your only solution that _does_ support two different users on the same computer is the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Server_ Edition.